# CSE API Google Custom PHP

Tags: php, api, google-custom-search

I am trying to get the first 50 results of the Google Custom Search API (CSE) into an array, but when I try to do it with the code like below it gives a empty array.

When I log the $request and copy and paste that url into my browser it gives me the correct json file. Am I overlooking something here?

```
$apiKey = "theapikey";
$query = "news";
$items = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

  $ch = curl_init();

  $request = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?" .
    "q=" . urlencode( "$query" ) . 
    "&cx=013594553343653397533:q-qkkaltmay" .
    "&key=" . $apiKey .
    "&start=" . ( ($i - 1)*10 + 1 );

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  $output = json_decode($output);

  foreach( $output->items as $result ) {

    if ($url = $result->link && trim($url)) $items[] = $url;

  } 

}

echo json_encode($items);
```

**EDIT**

When logging the $output it gives the correct JSON output as seen below:

```
'{ "kind": "customsearch#search", "url": { "type": "application/json", "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&cref={cref?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json" }, "queries": { "request": [ { "title": "Google Custom Search - news", "totalResults": "841000000", "searchTerms": "news", "count": 10, "startIndex": 1, "inputEncoding": "utf8", "outputEncoding": "utf8", "safe": "off", "cx": "013594553343653397533:q-qkkaltmay" } ], "nextPage": [ { "title": "Google Custom Search - news", "totalResults": "841000000", "searchTerms": "news", "count": 10, "startIndex": 11, "inputEncoding": "utf8", "outputEncoding": "utf8", "safe": "off", "cx": "013594553343653397533:q-qkkaltmay" } ] }, "context": { "title": "Oneseo.nl" }, "searchInformation": { "searchTime": 0.917402, "formattedSearchTime": "0.92", "totalResults": "841000000", "formattedTotalResults": "841,000,000" }, "items": [ { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "Google News", "htmlTitle": "Google \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e", "link": "https://news.google.com/", "displayLink": "news.google.com", "snippet": "Comprehensive up-to-date news coverage, aggregated from sources all over the \\nworld by Google News.", "htmlSnippet": "Comprehensive up-to-date \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e coverage, aggregated from sources all over the \\u003cbr\\u003e\\nworld by Google \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e.", "cacheId": "ozdoT-F6oa4J", "formattedUrl": "https://news.google.com/", "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e.google.com/", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "128", "height": "78", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTFbmICFKb9gonQbJKw-nY854Wow0ZOTlO6eoDFhwuBDdkOWSaOyxnioQ" } ], "metatags": [ { "apple-itunes-app": "app-id=913753848", "referrer": "origin" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "http://playfoundation.net/wp-content/themes/playfoundation/images/logo_header.png" } ] } }, { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "Fox News - Breaking News Updates | Latest News Headlines ...", "htmlTitle": "Fox \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e - Breaking \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e Updates | Latest \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e Headlines ...", "link": "http://www.foxnews.com/", "displayLink": "www.foxnews.com", "snippet": "Breaking News, Latest News and Current News from FOXNews.com. Breaking \\nnews and video. Latest Current News: U.S., World, Entertainment, Health, ...", "htmlSnippet": "Breaking \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e, Latest \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e and Current \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e from FOXNews.com. Breaking \\u003cbr\\u003e\\n\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e and video. Latest Current \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e: U.S., World, Entertainment, Health, ...", "formattedUrl": "www.foxnews.com/", "htmlFormattedUrl": "www.fox\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e.com/", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "225", "height": "225", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGg3hOcH41DZUMq6UBPeop8SuCOJo9qNCXmkWVCo29yRXtW0z0AlTksmsu" } ], "metatags": [ { "pagetype": "homepage", "dc.title": "Fox News - Breaking News Updates | Latest News Headlines | Photos & News Videos", "dc.description": "Breaking News, Latest News and Current News from FOXNews.com. Breaking news and video. Latest Current News: U.S., World, Entertainment, Health, Business, Technology, Politics, Sports.", "dc.language": "en-US", "dc.publisher": "FOX News", "dc.date": "2017/04/04", "dc.format": "text/html", "dc.type": "Collection", "dc.subject": "news, breaking news, latest news, current news, world news, national news", "dcterms.abstract": "Breaking News, Latest News and Current News from FOXNews.com. Breaking news and video. Latest Current News: U.S., World, Entertainment, Health, Business, Technology, Politics, Sports.", "dcterms.created": "2017-04-04 13:02:19 PM", "dcterms.modified": "2017-04-04 13:02:19 PM", "prism.genre": "homePage", "prism.aggregationtype": "root", "prism.channel": "fnc", "prism.section": "root", "og:title": "Fox News", "og:description": "Fair & Balanced", "og:type": "website", "og:image": "http://global.fncstatic.com/static/v/all/img/og/og-fn-foxnews.jpg", "og:url": "http://www.foxnews.com", "og:site_name": "Fox News", "twitter:account_id": "1367531", "vr:canonical": "http://www.foxnews.com/home.html", "twitter:card": "app", "twitter:app:id:iphone": "367623543", "twitter:app:url:iphone": "//itunes.apple.com/us/app/fox-news/id367623543?mt=8", "twitter:app:id:ipad": "436484582", "twitter:app:url:ipad": "//itunes.apple.com/us/app/fox-news-for-ipad/id436484582?mt=8", "twitter:app:id:googleplay": "com.foxnews.android", "twitter:app:url:googleplay": "//play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxnews.android" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "http://global.fncstatic.com/static/v/all/img/og/og-fn-foxnews.jpg" } ] } }, { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "Yahoo News - Latest News & Headlines", "htmlTitle": "Yahoo \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e - Latest \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e & Headlines", "link": "https://www.yahoo.com/news/", "displayLink": "www.yahoo.com", "snippet": "The latest news and headlines from Yahoo! News. Get breaking news stories and \\n... trend — the climate is changing,” Scott Pruitt said on “Fox News Sunday.", "htmlSnippet": "The latest \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e and headlines from Yahoo! \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e. Get breaking \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e stories and \\u003cbr\\u003e\\n... trend — the climate is changing,” Scott Pruitt said on “Fox \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e Sunday.", "cacheId": "5_0_5w8SWZUJ", "formattedUrl": "https://www.yahoo.com/news/", "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.yahoo.com/\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e/", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "225", "height": "225", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsu8h2qPcbEySow_b11yLyETddWLbICdJLk1xWXl-3molDDR1MTHSgF0Nw" } ], "metatags": [ { "msapplication-tilecolor": "#6e329d", "msapplication-tileimage": "https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/p/presentation/images/icons/win8-tile-1484740.png", "referrer": "origin", "theme-color": "#400090", "twitter:dnt": "on", "twitter:site": "@Yahoo", "application-name": "Yahoo News - Latest News & Headlines", "twitter:card": "summary", "apple-itunes-app": "app-id=304158842", "twitter:description": "The latest news and headlines from Yahoo! News. Get breaking news stories and in-depth coverage with videos and photos.", "twitter:image": "https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/social/images/social_default_logo-1481777.png", "twitter:image:src": "https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/social/images/social_default_logo-1481777.png", "twitter:title": "Yahoo News - Latest News & Headlines", "og:type": "website", "fb:app_id": "90376669494", "og:description": "The latest news and headlines from Yahoo! News. Get breaking news stories and in-depth coverage with videos and photos.", "og:image": "https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/social/images/social_default_logo-1481777.png", "og:title": "Yahoo News - Latest News & Headlines" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "https://s.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/social/images/social_default_logo-1481777.png" } ] } }, { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "Home - BBC News", "htmlTitle": "Home - BBC \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e", "link": "http://www.bbc.com/news", "displayLink": "www.bbc.com", "snippet": "Visit BBC News for up-to-the-minute news, breaking news, video, audio and \\nfeature stories. BBC News provides trusted World and UK news as well as local \\nand ...", "htmlSnippet": "Visit BBC \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e for up-to-the-minute \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e, breaking \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e, video, audio and \\u003cbr\\u003e\\nfeature stories. BBC \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e provides trusted World and UK \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e as well as local \\u003cbr\\u003e\\nand ...", "cacheId": "mSK5l2l2Z8gJ", "formattedUrl": "www.bbc.com/news", "htmlFormattedUrl": "www.bbc.com/\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "300", "height": "168", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTci4iZWnnJwADVgtU2-OKQapnOe9u0DRLuhVVolGKS6tSXatkpkInkcwvR" } ], "metatags": [ { "x-country": "us", "x-audience": "US", "cps_audience": "US", "cps_changequeueid": "1491309361", "og:title": "Home - BBC News", "og:type": "website", "og:description": "Visit BBC News for up-to-the-minute news, breaking news, video, audio and feature stories. BBC News provides trusted World and UK news as well as local and regional perspectives. Also entertainment, business, science, technology and health news.", "og:site_name": "BBC News", "og:locale": "en_GB", "article:author": "https://www.facebook.com/bbcnews", "article:section": "Home", "og:url": "http://www.bbc.com/news", "og:image": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/special/2015/newsspec_10857/bbc_news_logo.png?cb=1", "twitter:card": "summary_large_image", "twitter:site": "@BBCWorld", "twitter:title": "Home - BBC News", "twitter:description": "Visit BBC News for up-to-the-minute news, breaking news, video, audio and feature stories. BBC News provides trusted World and UK news as well as local and regional perspectives. Also entertainment, business, science, technology and health news.", "twitter:creator": "@BBCWorld", "twitter:image:src": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/special/2015/newsspec_10857/bbc_news_logo.png?cb=1", "twitter:image:alt": "BBC News", "twitter:domain": "www.bbc.com", "apple-mobile-web-app-title": "BBC News", "application-name": "BBC News", "msapplication-tileimage": "http://static.bbci.co.uk/news/1.185.01424/windows-eight-icon-144x144.png", "msapplication-tilecolor": "#bb1919", "mobile-web-app-capable": "yes", "theme-color": "#bb1919", "fb:app_id": "1609039196070050", "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", "fb:admins": "100004154058350" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/special/2015/newsspec_10857/bbc_news_logo.png?cb=1" } ] } }, { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "CNN - Breaking News, Latest News and Videos", "htmlTitle": "CNN - Breaking \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e, Latest \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e and Videos", "link": "http://www.cnn.com/", "displayLink": "www.cnn.com", "snippet": "View the latest news and breaking news today for U.S., world, weather, \\nentertainment, politics and health at CNN.com.", "htmlSnippet": "View the latest \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e and breaking \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e today for U.S., world, weather, \\u003cbr\\u003e\\nentertainment, politics and health at CNN.com.", "cacheId": "XBvJ7pr5NuMJ", "formattedUrl": "www.cnn.com/", "htmlFormattedUrl": "www.cnn.com/", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "240", "height": "135", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSah4YYrAeT7KitOlrn05VYrUmdSHPoJIn3X0Y9b0UIbLitUTgfq9EfK0I" } ], "metatags": [ { "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0", "section": "homepage", "og:pubdate": "2014-02-19T19:15:05Z", "pubdate": "2014-02-19T19:15:05Z", "lastmod": "2017-04-04T09:55:12Z", "og:url": "http://www.cnn.com", "og:title": "CNN - Breaking News, Latest News and Videos", "twitter:title": "CNN - Breaking News, Latest News and Videos", "og:description": "View the latest news and breaking news today for U.S., world, weather, entertainment, politics and health at CNN.com.", "twitter:description": "View the latest news and breaking news today for U.S., world, weather, entertainment, politics and health at CNN.com.", "og:site_name": "CNN", "twitter:card": "summary_large_image", "og:type": "website", "vr:canonical": "http://www.cnn.com", "fb:app_id": "80401312489", "fb:pages": "5550296508,18793419640" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "http://i2.cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/170215152157-mitch-mcconnell-02-13-2017-medium-tease.jpg" } ] } }, { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "ABC News – Breaking News, Latest News, Headlines & Videos", "htmlTitle": "ABC \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e – Breaking \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e, Latest \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e, Headlines & Videos", "link": "http://abcnews.go.com/", "displayLink": "abcnews.go.com", "snippet": "Your trusted source for breaking news, analysis, exclusive interviews, headlines, \\nand videos at ABCNews.com.", "htmlSnippet": "Your trusted source for breaking \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e, analysis, exclusive interviews, headlines, \\u003cbr\\u003e\\nand videos at ABCNews.com.", "formattedUrl": "abcnews.go.com/", "htmlFormattedUrl": "abc\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e.go.com/", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "113", "height": "45", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS54v1exB6-NmndnkMTm8uA3m1i5504sntPI30mKnkdSFZ3-gKwxe3t3Q" } ], "metatags": [ { "author": "ABC News", "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2017 ABC News Internet Ventures", "viewport": "initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no", "msvalidate.01": "0EABD001D404EA9DDE2025E9E4F14CAF", "application-name": "ABC News", "msapplication-tileimage": "http://a.abcnews.com/assets/images/abcn_logo_144x144.png", "msapplication-tilecolor": "#2368BA", "msapplication-id": "ABC.ABCNews", "msapplication-packagefamilyname": "ABC.ABCNews_x0jz7fs5f51ac", "fb:admins": "704409894", "fb:app_id": "4942312939", "fb_title": "ABC News", "og:site_name": "ABC News", "og:title": "ABC News", "og:description": "Your trusted source for breaking news, analysis, exclusive interviews, headlines, and videos at ABCNews.com", "og:url": "http://abcnews.go.com", "og:type": "website", "twitter:app:name:iphone": "ABC News", "twitter:app:id:iphone": "300255638", "twitter:app:url:iphone": "abcnewsiphone://link/home", "twitter:app:name:ipad": "ABC News", "twitter:app:id:ipad": "306934135", "twitter:app:url:ipad": "abcnewsipad://link/home", "twitter:image": "http://a.abcnews.com/assets/beta/assets/abcn_images/abc_logo_aluminum.png", "al:iphone:url": "abcnewsiphone://link/home", "al:iphone:app_store_id": "300255638", "al:iphone:app_name": "ABC News - Breaking US & World News", "al:ipad:url": "abcnewsipad://link/home", "al:ipad:app_store_id": "380520716", "al:ipad:app_name": "ABC News for iPad", "og:image": "http://a.abcnews.com/assets/beta/assets/abcn_images/abc_logo_aluminum.png", "og:image:type": "image/jpeg", "og:image:width": "120", "og:image:height": "48" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "http://a.abcnews.com/assets/beta/assets/abcn_images/abc_logo_aluminum.png" } ], "sitenavigationelement": [ { "name": "U.S.", "url": "U.S." } ] } }, { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "Technology News - CNET News - CNET", "htmlTitle": "Technology \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e - CNET \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e - CNET", "link": "https://www.cnet.com/news/", "displayLink": "www.cnet.com", "snippet": "CNET news editors and reporters provide top technology news, with investigative \\nreporting and in-depth coverage of tech issues and events.", "htmlSnippet": "CNET \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e editors and reporters provide top technology \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e, with investigative \\u003cbr\\u003e\\nreporting and in-depth coverage of tech issues and events.", "cacheId": "D5omcMdx0UoJ", "formattedUrl": "https://www.cnet.com/news/", "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.cnet.com/\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e/", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "200", "height": "200", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFDTYBZkjsnKgtJZGd4-TRcI5yvVdehDx-fJMHhWvZT9duTfoz2nvXuthe" } ], "metatags": [ { "theme-color": "#B80000", "apple-mobile-web-app-capable": "yes", "apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style": "black-translucent", "al:ios:app_name": "CNET", "al:ios:app_store_id": "383989837", "al:ios:url": "http://www.cnet.com/news/?search=toapp", "og:site_name": "CNET", "og:title": "Technology News", "og:description": "CNET news editors and reporters provide top technology news, with investigative reporting and in-depth coverage of tech issues and events.", "og:image": "https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/fly/bundles/cnetcore/images/logos/cnet-redball-large.jpg", "og:type": "website", "og:url": "https://www.cnet.com/news/", "fb:app_id": "16995676698", "fb:admins": "100001036810388", "article:publisher": "https://www.facebook.com/cnet", "twitter:account_id": "30261067", "p:domain_verify": "47524839a64b83c951afca9ef6c838e0", "msapplication-tooltip": "Product reviews and prices, software downloads, and tech news - CNET", "msapplication-starturl": "https://www.cnet.com/", "msapplication-window": "width=1024;height=768", "msapplication-navbutton-color": "#424244", "msapplication-task": "name=Home; action-uri=https://www.cnet.com/; icon-uri=https://www.cnet.com/favicon.ico", "viewport": "width=device-width" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/fly/bundles/cnetcore/images/logos/cnet-redball-large.jpg" } ] } }, { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "News: U.S. and World News Headlines : NPR", "htmlTitle": "\\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e: U.S. and World \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e Headlines : NPR", "link": "http://www.npr.org/sections/news/", "displayLink": "www.npr.org", "snippet": "US National Public Radio audio broadcast and text news stories and \\ncommentaries.", "htmlSnippet": "US National Public Radio audio broadcast and text \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e stories and \\u003cbr\\u003e\\ncommentaries.", "formattedUrl": "www.npr.org/sections/news/", "htmlFormattedUrl": "www.npr.org/sections/\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e/", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "300", "height": "168", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZtjgQjLumkf7-TV8VZbNq0qDy9qWZpVMEFb1AB8c93I2EKD7rKrIAmJqn" } ], "metatags": [ { "rating": "General", "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no", "date": "2017-03-27", "og:title": "News", "og:url": "http://www.npr.org/sections/news/", "og:type": "article", "og:description": "NPR news, audio, and podcasts. Coverage of breaking stories, national and world news, politics, business, science, technology, and extended coverage of major national and world events.", "og:image": "https://media.npr.org/include/images/facebook-default-wide.jpg?s=1400", "og:site_name": "NPR.org", "fb:app_id": "138837436154588", "fb:pages": "10643211755", "twitter:card": "summary", "twitter:site": "@NPR", "twitter:domain": "npr.org" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "https://media.npr.org/include/images/facebook-default-wide.jpg?s=1400" } ] } }, { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "NBC News - Breaking News & Top Stories - Latest World, US ...", "htmlTitle": "NBC \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e - Breaking \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e & Top Stories - Latest World, US ...", "link": "http://www.nbcnews.com/", "displayLink": "www.nbcnews.com", "snippet": "Go to NBCNews.com for breaking news, videos, and the latest top stories in \\nworld news, business, politics, health and pop culture.", "htmlSnippet": "Go to NBCNews.com for breaking \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e, videos, and the latest top stories in \\u003cbr\\u003e\\nworld \\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e, business, politics, health and pop culture.", "cacheId": "MeitRpLVG58J", "formattedUrl": "www.nbcnews.com/", "htmlFormattedUrl": "www.nbc\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e.com/", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "275", "height": "183", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRn1wYM8bsR4RIkcYRwO24u3ma3AQS-I6bS5HcN2DqDGLUbWvo78B2uFlOY" } ], "metatags": [ { "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1", "fb:app_id": "10150138890205613", "og:site_name": "NBC News", "og:description": "Go to NBCNews.com for breaking news, videos, and the latest top stories in world news, business, politics, health and pop culture.", "og:title": "NBC News - Breaking News & Top Stories - Latest World, US & Local News", "og:url": "http://www.nbcnews.com/", "og:type": "article", "og:image": "https://nodeassets.nbcnews.com/images/og-nbcnews200x200.gif", "twitter:card": "summary", "twitter:site": "NBCNews", "twitter:title": "NBC News - Breaking News & Top Stories - Latest World, US & Local News", "twitter:description": "Go to NBCNews.com for breaking news, videos, and the latest top stories in world news, business, politics, health and pop culture.", "twitter:creator": "NBCNews", "twitter:image": "https://nodeassets.nbcnews.com/images/og-nbcnews200x200.gif", "apple-itunes-app": "app-id=319740707, app-argument=http://www.nbcnews.com/", "news_keywords": "Cover", "blitz": "mu-e1e842c9-946002e6-ea8f0454-41b29546" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "http://media3.s-nbcnews.com/i/newscms/2017_13/1952106/4217-equal-pay-1215p-rs_ced1e4a6c468f0b0313155ac0892a299.jpg" } ], "newsarticle": [ { "headline": "McDonald\'s makes pizza? Here\'s where to find it", "name": "McDonald\'s makes pizza? Here\'s where to find it" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media1.s-nbcnews.com/i/newscms/2017_13/1951916/gettyimages-631616260_665ef4d9a3d3e0d236d5f67390733e12.jpg", "headline": "Second Teen Arrested in Live-Streamed Sexual Assault", "name": "Second Teen Arrested in Live-Streamed Sexual Assault" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media3.s-nbcnews.com/i/newscms/2017_13/1952106/4217-equal-pay-1215p-rs_ced1e4a6c468f0b0313155ac0892a299.jpg", "headline": "What Is Your State Doing About The Gender Wage Gap?", "name": "What Is Your State Doing About The Gender Wage Gap?" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media4.s-nbcnews.com/i/MSNBC/Components/Video/201704/f_dc_trump_egypt_170403.jpg", "headline": "Trump Welcomes Egyptian President to the White House", "name": "Trump Welcomes Egyptian President to the White House" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media1.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Video/201703/f_trump_forgets_eo_170331.nbcnews-fp-840-360.jpg", "headline": "Watch Trump Leave Executive Order Ceremony Without Signing", "name": "Watch Trump Leave Executive Order Ceremony Without Signing" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media1.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Video/201703/f_trump_forgets_eo_170331.nbcnews-fp-320-280.jpg", "headline": "Watch Trump Leave Executive Order Ceremony Without Signing", "name": "Watch Trump Leave Executive Order Ceremony Without Signing" }, { "headline": "Watch Trump Leave Executive Order Ceremony Without Signing", "name": "Watch Trump Leave Executive Order Ceremony Without Signing" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media1.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Video/201704/f_fair_explosion_170401.nbcnews-fp-840-360.jpg", "headline": "18 Hurt in Accidental Explosion at French Carnival", "name": "18 Hurt in Accidental Explosion at French Carnival" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media1.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Video/201704/f_fair_explosion_170401.nbcnews-fp-320-280.jpg", "headline": "18 Hurt in Accidental Explosion at French Carnival", "name": "18 Hurt in Accidental Explosion at French Carnival" }, { "headline": "18 Hurt in Accidental Explosion at French Carnival", "name": "18 Hurt in Accidental Explosion at French Carnival" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Video/201704/x_30_nn_nkorea_new_170403.nbcnews-fp-840-360.jpg", "headline": "Lester Holt Speaks with Thae Yong-ho, Former North Korean Diplomat Who Defected", "name": "Lester Holt Speaks with Thae Yong-ho, Former North Korean Diplomat Who Defected" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Video/201704/x_30_nn_nkorea_new_170403.nbcnews-fp-320-280.jpg", "headline": "Lester Holt Speaks with Thae Yong-ho, Former North Korean Diplomat Who Defected", "name": "Lester Holt Speaks with Thae Yong-ho, Former North Korean Diplomat Who Defected" }, { "headline": "Lester Holt Speaks with Thae Yong-ho, Former North Korean Diplomat Who Defected", "name": "Lester Holt Speaks with Thae Yong-ho, Former North Korean Diplomat Who Defected" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Video/201704/f_lon_moscow_170403.nbcnews-fp-840-360.jpg", "headline": "Eyewitness Describes Horror of Russian Metro Blast Attack", "name": "Eyewitness Describes Horror of Russian Metro Blast Attack" }, { "thumbnailurl": "http://media4.s-nbcnews.com/j/MSNBC/Components/Video/201704/f_lon_moscow_170403.nbcnews-fp-320-280.jpg", "headline": "Eyewitness Describes Horror of Russian Metro Blast Attack", "name": "Eyewitness Describes Horror of Russian Metro Blast Attack" }, { "headline": "Eyewitness Describes Horror of Russian Metro Blast Attack", "name": "Eyewitness Describes Horror of Russian Metro Blast Attack" } ] } }, { "kind": "customsearch#result", "title": "News - Salon.com", "htmlTitle": "\\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e - Salon.com", "link": "http://www.salon.com/category/news/", "displayLink": "www.salon.com", "snippet": "Roger Ailes\' pleasure palace: Fox News faces another lawsuit because of ex-\\nboss\' alleged sexual harassment. The litigation keeps coming even after Roger ...", "htmlSnippet": "Roger Ailes' pleasure palace: Fox \\u003cb\\u003eNews\\u003c/b\\u003e faces another lawsuit because of ex-\\u003cbr\\u003e\\nboss' alleged sexual harassment. The litigation keeps coming even after Roger ...", "cacheId": "QW0IXhYFiNAJ", "formattedUrl": "www.salon.com/category/news/", "htmlFormattedUrl": "www.salon.com/category/\\u003cb\\u003enews\\u003c/b\\u003e/", "pagemap": { "cse_thumbnail": [ { "width": "317", "height": "159", "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRHEs62AnmQE2AXoPWhVGDp6nE19_kroisV-e_F18x0DqsEoZNQj_CQunKv" } ], "metatags": [ { "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", "apple-itunes-app": "app-id=549374205, app-argument=http://www.salon.com/", "fb:pages": "120680396518", "title": "News - Salon.com", "og:title": "News - Salon.com", "og:url": "http://www.salon.com/category/news/", "og:image": "http://media.salon.com/images/salon-twitter-card.jpg", "og:description": "12667731", "og:type": "article", "fb:app_id": "456294607741273", "og:site_name": "Salon", "twitter:card": "summary_large_image", "twitter:site": "@salon", "twitter:title": "News - Salon.com", "twitter:description": "12667731", "twitter:image": "http://media.salon.com/images/salon-twitter-card.jpg" } ], "cse_image": [ { "src": "http://media.salon.com/images/salon-twitter-card.jpg" } ] } } ] } '[]
```

Comment: Can you run `var_export($output);` after the curl_exec and update your question with the results please?

Comment: This shows the complete JSON

Comment: Is it too large to post in the question area? It would allow readers to duplicate your problem.

Comment: Well it's a JSON output, and a bit large indeed. I will add it to my question

Comment: Try this: `if ($url = $result->link) $items[] = trim($url);`

Comment: That results in: '{ "error": { "code": 500, "message": null } } '[]

Comment: One more: `if ($result->link) $items[] = trim($result->link);`

Comment: It works! I was getting to my limit of free requests per day lol